# LazyLoading routing each time creates new Component in memory and does not destroy it after loading new same component

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I use:

- nativescript 4.2
- angular 6.0.0
- page-router-outlet
- navigation from page to page by 'lazyloading' (lateral navigation):

  export const routes = [
      {
          path: "",
          loadChildren: "~/pages/start-page/start-page.module#StartPageModule"
      },
      {
          path: "login",
          loadChildren: "~/pages/login/login.module#LoginModule"
      }, ...
- navigate with RouterExtensions with 'clearHistory = true'

When i navigate from page 'Home' to another page and return to 'Home' i see in memory two component 'HomeComponent'. When I repeat the operation their becomes three, four, five, .....

[chrome debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppRtX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try to this for lazy loading routing.

**app-routing.module.ts :-**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
{ path: "startpage", loadChildren: "~/pages/start-page/start-page.module#StartPageModule" },
{ path: "login", loadChildren: "~/pages/login/login.module#LoginModule" }
]

@NgModule({
imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Redirection Code:-**

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { isIOS } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";

constructor(private zone: NgZone,
private _routerExtensions: RouterExtensions){ }

gotoStartPage() {
setTimeout(() => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this._routerExtensions.navigate(["startpage"], {
            clearHistory: (isIOS) ? true : false,
        });
    });
}, 500);
}
```

Comment: Luke, thanks so much for trying to help. I tried this option, but unfortunately it did not help. Now I have a situation such that one group of pages works correctly, the others do not. I observe and understand the reason. If I get to the bottom of the truth I will share my achievements here.